# How to create .jar file in IntelliJ for Maven scala+spark project

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, scala-ide

IntelliJ-IDEA is new for me .. I used to work with `SCALA-IDE`. for current project i have to use `IntelliJ`.
I tried in stackoverflow to find "How to crate .jar file  of scala maven project created in Intellij"

I found:

1. install SBT and on CMD type "sbt package"
2. install maven and on cnd type "maven package"
3. some says in `intellij` at right hand side there will be two options, one is `maven`, one is ant. Click on maven. U can see the modules. Click on the module un want to build. Expand module, expand the life cycle, click on install

My question is:

**what is the best way to create `.jar` file in `Intellij` for maven project ). I have added all scala and spark the dependencies to pom.xml**

FYI: I think the meaning of having a tool is usefully when you don't have to go to `cmd` and type `"sbt package"` or `"maven package"` . just a mouse click should work for you Like `scala-IDE`

Comment: Do you mean so called fat-jar which includes all dependencies listed in the pom, so that later you can run smth like `java -jar mylar.jar`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Build Project` from menu.

> Build > Build Project

Or if you want more fine grain controls use the `Maven Projects` tab on the right to `package`.

[image]